# chrome extension how content script run on a package app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm making a chrome package app. Here is my manifest.json

```
  "app": {
"launch": {
  "local_path": "main.html"
}

"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*"],
  "js": ["jquery-1.7.min.js", "content_script.js"],
  "all_frame": "true"
}
```

Why my content script can't run on main.html? Can content script run on a package app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts cannot run at the `chrome-extension:` protocol <sup>[[1](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html)]</sup>. For this reason, the content script will not run at your app.

Include the scripts in `main.html`:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="content_script.js"></script>
```

[[1](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html)]: The only permitted protocols are `http:`, `https:` and `file:`. For all other protocols, Content scripts will not be injected, even when `<all_urls>` is specified.

Comment: so the script is just a script but not a content script for chrome extension? and can't pass message?

Comment: @user1070827 Scripts in extension pages have full access to the `chrome.*` API. Content scripts run in an environment between a page, and the extension: Content scripts do [**not**](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) have access to any `window` object in the page, and only *some* of the   [`chrome.extension.*`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#content%20scripts) methods.